# How to add SWRL rules to an Ontology using Java or pellet?

Tags: java, owl, pellet, swrl

Instead of using Protégé to add rules to my ontology, I want to use Java or pellet to add SWRL rule to the ontology.

For example, this is the rule that I want to import into my ontology:

> [Course(?x),teacherOf(?y,?x),worksFor(?y,?z)] =>
>   [coursePresentedInUniversity(?x,?z)]

I want to add the following code into the ontology:

```
<swrl:Imp rdf:about="#CoursePresentedInUniversityRule">
    <swrl:head rdf:parseType="Collection">  
        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
                <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#coursePresentedInUniversity" />
                <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#x" />
                <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#z" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
    </swrl:head>
    <swrl:body rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <swrl:ClassAtom>
            <swrl:classPredicate rdf:resource="#Course" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#x" />
        </swrl:ClassAtom>

        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#teacherOf" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#y" />
            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#x" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
        <swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>
            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="#worksFor" />
            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="#y" />
            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="#z" />
        </swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom>

    </swrl:body>
</swrl:Imp>
```

Could anybody point me out to a sample code to do that?

Actually, I wrote the following code, but it didn't work!

```
    Rule mynewRule=new Rule(ruleHead,ruleBody);
    PelletReasoner pelletReasoner =com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner(testOntology );
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase=pelletReasoner.getKB();
    knowledgeBase.addRule(mynewRule);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with Java code is through the OWL API - the `OWLDataFactory` class has methods for creating SWRL rules, and the resulting rules can be added to an ontology and saved - it is the same process used by Protege 4 and 5.

Documentation is available [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: Hi I'm trying to add swrl rule and run reasoner using java and owl api but, i'm lost could you help me with piece of example please Enayat , Ignazio